# google app engine throwing Unknown error: '4' all of a sudden

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My java based app on GAE was working great but now all of a sudden I'm getting this exception on gae but works great on local:

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesException: Unknown error: '4'
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:458)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Is it possible you have code which attempts to find a module by name, using the string "4" as a possible module name?

Comment: If you can't manage to determine the cause of the issue as originating in your own code, feel free to create an issue in the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-appengine/issues/list), uploading an example app or minimal code snippets which you've found will allow a deployed app to reproduce the error.

Comment: It seemed to resolve itself after a few days. So guess it is a glitch in App engine and nothing to do with my code. Thanks for the pointers though

Answer (score 1):

There was a transient issue that caused this error. We are working towards a permanent fix which will be out in 1.9.28.

This issue was [acknowledged and fixed](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12468), as described in the Public Issue Tracker for App Engine.

Comment: Apologies, this issue was reported as a production issue, therefore the app id of the reporter is requiring the thread to be protected. It could possibly be removed shortly and opened-up, but at any rate, I've edited my answer slightly to give echo of what's said there, especially to fit Stack Overflow quality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update app engine sdk version to latest version (1.9.27).